# Display Spring validation error with jQuery plugin

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am able to validate form and display Spring validation error with Spring form tag. Instead of displaying as HTML markup how can I display those errors using jQuery Noty Plugin?

Controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/Register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView Registeruser(@ModelAttribute("registerBean") @Valid RegisterBean registerBean, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        mv.setViewName("index");
        mv.addObject(registerBean);
    } else {
        boolean registered = userservice.RegisterUser(registerBean);
        if (registered) {
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>(1);
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(registerBean.getEmail(), registerBean.getPassword(), authList);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            mv.setViewName("auth/Home");
        } else {
            mv.setViewName("index");
        }
    }
    return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which view technology you are using. I assume that `JSP` is in use.

First you should render any error message into a separate hidden container.
In this example product is my `modelAttribute`. It is completely up to you what you are showing to your users in case of an error. In this example a unordered list of validation type on property and validation message will be shown.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<s:hasBindErrors name="product">
    <div id="error-noty" style="display:none;">
        <h3>You have errors in your input!</h3>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${errors.fieldErrors}" var="error">
                <li>${error.codes[1]} ${error.defaultMessage}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </div>
</s:hasBindErrors>
```

Then you should initialize `noty` only if a container with the selector `#error-noty` could be found in the page.
Hand over the html from the hidden container to `noty` and you're done.

```
<script>
    var errors = $('#error-noty');
    if(errors.html()) {
        noty({text: errors.html()});
    }
</script>
```

A working example can be found [here](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/blob/validation-noty/spring-mvc/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/product/edit.jsp).

Comment: Thnks @user3151168. I'll try this.

Comment: It worked but there is one problem. After registration i am redirecting user to Home page bt My url is not changing to returned modelView object. i have added my controller code. Please check.

Comment: You'll need to change `mv.setViewName("auth/Home");` to something like `mv.setViewName("redirect:/Home");` (I'll assume that you homepage is accessible under `/Home`). This instructs Spring MVC to send a redirect (HTTP 302) back to the browser with the given Location `/Home`. The browser than initiates a new HTTP GET request with the new URL to fetch the home page.